# "Quick Links" in control panel

Tags: control-panel

Is it possible to create a "Quick Link" in the control panel, similar to the way quick links function in ExpressionEngine?

If you have a Single that is frequently accessed by the client, it would be really helpful to save a link to the publish page right in the CP, rather than having the clients select Entries > Singles > Title every time they need to make an edit.

Comment: I wish this was there as well… help make it happen by voting for a [Quick Links feature on Craft's feedback site](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285730-plugin-ideas/suggestions/7232354-dashboard-quick-links-widget)!

Answer (score 2):

Not natively, but it would be pretty easy for a plugin to add a widget that does something like that.

I don't see anything currently on [Straight Up Craft](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins) that would fit that bill, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but a solution has since been created...

Check out the awesome **[Control Panel Nav](https://github.com/engram-design/CPNav)** plugin, which lets you add whatever custom links you'd like!

Answer (score 1):

To add some quick links to the dashboard, check out the **[RichTextWidget](https://github.com/gilleard/RichTextWidget)** plugin: It lets you easily add any kind of text – including a list of hyperlinks – to the control panel's main page.

(One caveat: The richtext panel can only be set on a per-user basis – not to a whole admin group.)